# Why open function dose not work?

Tags: python

I can not understand what is happening in my code.It can not open the folder.

```
import urllib

def read_text ():

    quotes = open ("C:\Users\HP\Downloads\book\just.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print("content_of_file")
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check)
    output = connecting.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()

read_text()
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: When you run the code, do you get any errors?

Comment: Hold up. Are you sure it's supposed to be `output = connecting.read()` and not `output = connection.read()`? `connecting` does not exist so I guess you're getting `NameError`s (unless the code you showed us just contains a typo).

Comment: syntax error.I checked. But I could not find any error.

Comment: @FahimShahriar What is the _full_ error traceback you get?

Comment: Try running it in the console, screen shot the console, and then send us the screen shot.

Comment: And are you sure `'...\just.txt'` exists or has content?

Comment: @Sean Francis N. Ballais Yes

Comment: At this point then, it'd be best to show us the output from the command prompt, @FahimShahriar. An image would do.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais  error messages should be provided as *text* not as a screenshot

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I was just suggesting to use an image instead since it's harder to read the full traceback here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your file path contains the character `\U` which has a special meaning in Python (Unicode). You are probably receiving an error similar to:

```
  File "C:/Python34/Testing.py",
    quotes = open ("C:\Users\HP\Downloads\book\just.txt")
                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

When this happens you will need to use a double backslash:

```
def read_text():
    quotes = open("C:\\Users\HP\Downloads\book\just.txt")
```

Comment: ========== RESTART: C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py ==========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py", line 16, in <module>
    read_text()
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py", line 4, in read_text
    quotes = open ("C:\\Users\HP\Downloads\book\just.txt")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\x08ook\\just.txt'

Comment: @FahimShahriar, I think you missed adding an additional slash between `'Downloads'` and `'books'`. It should be `C:\\Users\HP\Downloads\\book\\just.txt'`.

Comment: @Sean Francis N. Ballais   content_of_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py", line 17, in <module>
    read_text()
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py", line 9, in read_text
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py", line 12, in check_profanity
    connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check)

Comment: @FahimShahriar, is that the full traceback? Also, try replacing the backslashes with forward slashes.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais , and I also tried. but it does not work

Comment: @FahimShahriar, the traceback you commented earlier, is that the full traceback that you get?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais, when I  use forward slashes then ,Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py", line 17, in <module>
    read_text()
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/python/check_profanity.py", line 5, in read_text
    quotes = open("C:/Users/HP/Downloadsbook/just.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/HP/Downloadsbook/just.txt'

Comment: @FahimShahriar, replace the `open()` function you have with `open("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/book/just.txt")`. From the traceback, it seems that you are forgetting a slash between `'Downloads'` and `'book'`.